# spring cassandra data Version 2.1.4 pagination

Tags: java, spring-boot, cassandra, pagination, spring-data-cassandra

As per the documentation : https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/cassandra/docs/2.1.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories.limit-query-result

Spring cassandra data have made it easy to get the pagination info.
But I can't get this to work.

Repo, Call and Errors:

**1. Reactive Call**

*Repo*:

```
public interface MyRepository extends ReactiveCassandraRepository<MyClass, String> {
  @Query("select * from my_keyspace.my_table where solr_query = ?0")
  Mono<Slice<MyClass>> findMono(String solrQuery, Pageable page);
}
```

*Call:*

```
 Mono<Slice<MyClass>>  repository.findMono(queryString, CassandraPageRequest.first(20));
```

*Error:*

> "exceptionDescription":"org.springframework.core.codec.CodecException:
>   Type definition error: [simple type, class
>   com.datastax.driver.core.PagingState]; nested exception is
>   com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No
>   serializer found for class com.datastax.driver.core.PagingState and no
>   properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception,
>   disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference
>   chain:
>   org.springframework.data.domain.SliceImpl[\"pageable\"]->org.springframework.data.cassandra.core.query.CassandraPageRequest[\"pagingState\"])","lines":["org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Encoder.encodeValue(AbstractJackson2Encoder.java:175)","org.springframework.http.codec.json.AbstractJackson2Encoder.lambda$encode$0(AbstractJackson2Encoder.java:122)","reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:100)","reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67)","reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:114)","reactor.core.publisher.FluxDefaultIfEmpty$DefaultIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxDefaultIfEmpty.java:92)","reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1476)","reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:241)","reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121)","reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1476)","reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoBufferAllSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollectList.java:118)","reactor.core.publisher.FluxTake$TakeFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxTake.java:424)","reactor.core.publisher.FluxTake$TakeFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxTake.java:404)","reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.fastPath(FluxIterable.java:311)","reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:198)"],

**2. Reactive with ReactiveSortingRepository**

*Repo:*

```
public interface LocationRepository extends ReactiveSortingRepository<MyClass, String> {
}
```

*Call:*

```
 repository.findAll(CassandraPageRequest.first(20))
```

*Error:*

> Syntax error: findAll can't be applied to CassandraPageRequest.

**3. Simple call to get the page.**

*Repo:*

```
public interface MyRepository extends CassandraRepository<MyClass, MyClassKey> {
Page<MyClass> findByKeyTerminalIdAndSolrQuery(String solrQuery, Pageable page);
}
```

*Error while starting:*

> Caused by: org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException:
>   Page queries are not supported. Use a Slice query.

**4. Using PagingAndSortingRepository**

*Repo:*

```
public interface MyRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<MyClass, MyClassKey> {

}
```

*Call:*

```
   Page<Vessel> vessels = repository.findAll(CassandraPageRequest.first(10));
```

*Error:*

> springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property
>   findAll found for type MyClass!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

The first example is the appropriate one:

```
public interface MyRepository extends ReactiveCassandraRepository<MyClass, String> {
  @Query("select * from my_keyspace.my_table where solr_query = ?0")
  Mono<Slice<MyClass>> findMono(String solrQuery, Pageable page);
}

Mono<Slice<MyClass>>  repository.findMono(queryString, CassandraPageRequest.first(20));
```

The issue is that Jackson cannot encode a `SliceImpl` (implementation of `Slice`) as you're passing it to WebFlux (according to the stack trace). So the query yields the right result but you need to pass on the `Slice` content, not the `Slice` itself if you want to JSON-encode it.

On a related note: `ReactiveCassandraRepository` does not implement `ReactiveSortingRepository` because Casandra queries with a `Sort` argument require always a `WHERE` clause. Looking at `ReactiveSortingRepository`, you'll see a `findAll(Sort)` method that does not take a filter criterion:

```
public interface ReactiveSortingRepository<T, ID> extends ReactiveCrudRepository<T, ID> {
    Flux<T> findAll(Sort sort);
}
```

Comment: Thank s response @mp911de. You are right.The error was mapping. But we need the PageRequest to fetch us the results from the offset position and not just from 0. when I retried this with:`repository.findMono(queryString, CassandraPageRequest.of(20, 30))`,   got the error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot create a Cassandra page request for an indexed page other than the first page (0)`. We need the repo to take a CassandraPageRequest which works with the non zero offset locations and return us the total count of the rows. even findAll of ReactiveSortingRepo fails for requirement.

Comment: Use `CassandraPageRequest.of(Pageable, PagingState)` to construct a continuation `CassandraPageRequest`

Comment: Thanks a lot @mp911de we have used pagingstate before. But Cassandra paging  have some limitation like its only forward fetching and we have to fetch all the pages leading up to the page we need. But it has nothing to do with spring data.

Comment: did you find a way?